# Check date in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

```
$dateFrom = '2019-10-14';
$dateTo = '2019-11-18';
```

1. check if $ dateFrom and $ dateTo have the correct date format
2. we will check if $ dateFrom is less than $ dateTo
   3.we check whether the number of days between $ dateFrom and $ dateTo is less than or equal to 60

How can I make this?

Comment: you need to convert them to epoch date format. then do the comparison. https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/php

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried `strtotime()` method and compared both dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $dateFrom = Carbon::create('2019-12-14');
    $dateTo = Carbon::create('2019-11-18');

    // diffInDays will give us $dateTo - $dateFrom.
    // False is to get a negative value if $dateTo is bigger than $dateFrom
    $diff = $dateFrom->diffInDays($dateTo, false);
    if ($diff >= 0) {
        // We have postitive difference so $dateFrom is older than $dateTo
        If ($diff <= 60) {
            // Hooray - we have positive difference that is less thn 60 days
        }
    } else {
        // $dateTo is before $dateFrom (negative difference)
    }
```

[Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) Is a good way to operate with DateTime in a human readable way.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is this;

```
$dateFrom = '2019-10-14';
$dateTo = '2019-11-18';

$formattedDateFrom = strtotime($dateFrom);
$formattedDateTo = strtotime($dateTo);

$compareval = false;

if($formattedDateFrom < $formattedDateTo){
    $compareval = true;
}

** to check for 60 days ** 
$val = $formattedDateTo - $formattedDateFrom;

$epchtimeframe = 86400 * 60; //this is to check 60 days in epoch val

$compareval2 = false;

if($epchtimeframe>= $val){
   $compareval2 = true;
}
```

Something like this basically.

Comment: also note that if you want to get the current datetime, its most accurate to use the `Carbon::now();` feature

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the format:

```
$dateFromInput = '2019-10-14';
$dateToInput = '2019-11-18';
$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';

$dateFrom = \DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $dateFrom);
$dateTo = \DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $dateTo); // Returns false if string does not have expected format

if (!$dateFrom instanceof \DateTime or $dateTo instanceof \DateTime) {
    throw new \Exception('Illegal date format'); // Or `return null`
}
```

Then continue with Udhayan Nair's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$dateFromInput = '2019-10-14';
$dateToInput = '2019-11-18';
$dateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateFromInput));
$dateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateToInput)); 
$compareval = false;
if($dateFrom < $dateTo){
$compareval = true;
}
$daydiff = false;
$x  = ceil(abs(strtotime($dateTo) - strtotime($dateFrom)) / 86400);
if( $x <= 60)
{
$daydiff = true;
}
echo $compareval;
echo $daydiff;
```

Output will be

```
11 (true true)
```